# ALSA individual PCM volume control

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pcm

I'm playing PCM sounds simultaneously using ALSA device "plug:dmix" (one call of snd_pcm_open() for each sound), but I can't find a way to control each sound's volume separately (like DirectSound does), I've only managed to set MASTER and PCM volumes, using simple mixer interface. Is there a way to do this using ALSA's C API? I know how to do it by hand, but I prefer to use the library API, if it is possible at all. Already searched the documentation and related questions, can't find an answer.

Comment: You have to add the `softvol` plugin.

Comment: ok... care to elaborate? Haven't found any details about this too.

Comment: Google "dmix softvol". And on most machines, the `default` device already does this.